# Two transform effects on one element

Tags: javascript, css-animations, css-transforms, animate.css

I am using Animate.css's slideInLeft effect on an element, which looks like this:

```
@keyframes slideInLeft {
  0% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translateX(-2000px);
  } 
  100% {
     transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

I also want this element to be vertically centered after sliding in. For this I use the styles:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
```

Unfortunately CSS animations using transform interfere with my vertical align technique. I could rewrite the animation so that it used translate3d with a "-50%" Y value, but the problem with doing this is that I don't want to force the content to be vertically centered on small screen sizes.

The solution I came up with was using Javascript to detect the screensize, then determine whether to add the .slideInLeft animation, or the .slideInLeftVC animation (.translate3d(0px, -50%, 0). This technique of applying the right animations on load time may work in many cases, but it doesn't seem to be the best solution. For example, if a user resized their window after loading the page, they would get the wrong animation. I was wondering if anyone knew any good techniques for working with multiple transforms.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us your HTML? A working jsfiddle would be helpful. Also to clarify - you want a -50% vertical axis transform only on certain window sizes? Is there no other options besides a transform to do this?

Comment: Hi Tim, here is the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CowboyDan32/pt7whpLk/    Yes, I want a -50% vertical axis in certain window sizes. The only thing I can think of is using the left/right properties, but this may also produce problems down the road. I think the problem would need to be solved using javascript